# When i fetched data it display only two records i want to display all list?

Tags: android

I have view as shown in image i fetched data and display it but it display only two records

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFlUQ.png)

Database has 33 items need to display all but it display only two

need some help

Thanks in advance

Please Help fast thanks again

THANK YOU

I have view as shown in image i fetched data and display it but it display only two records

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame); //Remember this is the FrameLayout area within your activity_main.xml
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, contentFrameLayout);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());



    DbHelper dbhelper = new DbHelper(this);

    try {
        dbhelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    districtList = dbhelper.getAllDistricts();
    adapter = new DistrictsAdapter(this, districtList);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}


// DbHelper Method

public List<Districts> getAllDistricts() {
    List<Districts> districtList = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM district;";
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Districts district = new Districts();
                district.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                district.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                district.setThumbnail(cursor.getBlob(2));
                     district.setFortscount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                districtList.add(district);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return districtList;

}


// DISTRICTSADAPTER


public class DistrictsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DistrictsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Districts> districtList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name, forts;
    public ImageView thumbnail;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        forts = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.forts);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    }
}


public DistrictsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Districts> districtList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.districtList = districtList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.district_card, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Districts district = districtList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(district.getName());
    holder.forts.setText(district.getFortscount() + " किल्ले");

    // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(district.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return districtList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: share your `DistrictsAdapter` with question

Comment: just one minute sir

Comment: added to the last of above code

Comment: try to print the size of your `districtList` in log

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and change according your code like table name and fields.

```
  public List<MyTableTwo> getMyItems() {
    List<MyTableTwo> mySuperList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + USER_TABLE_NAME ;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {
            MyTableTwo myTable = new MyTableTwo();
            myTable.itemName = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Item_Name")));
            myTable.weight = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Weight")));
            myTable.mrp = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("MRP")));
            myTable.barcod = (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("BARCODE")));

            mySuperList.add(myTable);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return mySuperList;
}
```